# Most general condition for an iterated integral to be well-defined

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, borel-sets

Let $I$ be an interval and $\omega$ be a probability density function so that $\int_{x \in I} \omega(x) \mathrm{d}x = 1$.

Moreover, let $c:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}_+$ be a Borel function, and $\gamma(\cdot |t)$ be a probability measure supported on $\mathbb{R}$ so that $\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \mathrm{d} \gamma(x | t)= 1, \ t \in I$.

Now, I am dealing with the following integral:
$$ \displaystyle \int_{t \in I} \omega(t) \left[ \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} c(x) \mathrm{d} \gamma(x | t) \right] \mathrm{d} t.$$

What is the most general condition I need on $\gamma$ so that the above integral is well-defined? Is there a more general way than assuming each $\gamma(\cdot | t)$ admits a density function (wrt the Lebesgue measure)?

Comment: You need to ensure that $t\mapsto \int_\mathbb{R} c(x)\mathrm{d}\gamma(x\mid t)$ is measurable. This holds, for example, if $t\mapsto \gamma(A\mid t)$ is measurable for each Borel set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. In this case $\gamma$ is called a Markov kernel. However, since you consider a specific function $c$ it should be sufficient to assume that $t\mapsto \gamma(A\mid t)$ is measurable for each $A$ in the sigma algebra generated by $c$.

Comment: Thank you @jakobdt, great to know re Markov kernel. If the outer integral was wrt an arbitrary measure rather than Lebesgue, do we then need $t \mapsto \gamma(A| t)$ to be measurable for each measurable $A$ wrt this arbitrary measure?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The measure in the outer integral is defined on a sigma algebra $\mathcal{E}$, and you then need $t\mapsto\gamma(A,t)$ to be $\mathcal{E}$-measurable.

Comment: Thanks; well-appreciated :)

Comment: @jakobdt please feel free to write your answer as a post so that I can approve it.
Last question to make sure I understand. Apologies:
What about the case where the inner integral has $t$ in $c$ instead of the inner measure, such as:
$$ \displaystyle \int_{t \in I} \omega(t) \left[ \int_{A} c(A, t) \mathrm{d} \gamma(A) \right] \mathrm{d} t.$$
Here $A$ is not necessarily a real number; it can even be the Borel sets. I guess all we need is a condition that $t \mapsto  \int_{A} c(A, t) \mathrm{d} \gamma(A) $ is Lebesgue measurable. Is it enough to say $c(A,t)$ is measurable in product space?

Comment: You use $A$ for both an integration variable and an integration domain so I'm not sure how to interpret the inner integral. Do you mean something like $$\int_A c(x,t)\,\gamma(\mathrm{d}x)$$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $A \in \mathcal{A}$ where $A$ is a set and $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of sets.

Comment: Ok. Then yes. Measurability w.r.t. the product sigma algebra is what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much!